# width attribute not working with d3 style

Tags: css, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to display bar graphs with width of each bar representing age. but using style method in d3, i am unable to apply width attribute to the bars (as checked by doing inspect element in browser). other attributes applied using style are working fine.

```
 function showData(clients){
        let max = d3.max(clients, (d) => {
            return (parseInt(d.age));
        })
        //console.log(max);

        let scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, parseInt(max)]).range([0, 100]);
        //console.log(scale);

        let join = container.selectAll('div').data(clients);

        join.enter().append('div')
            .text((d) => {
                return d.name + ' : ' + scale(parseInt(d.age));
            })
            .style('background-color', 'blue')
            .style('margin', '5px')
            .style('color', 'white')
            .style('width', (d) => {
                return parseInt(d.age)
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`css` width is [not just a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width):

```
width: 150px;
width: 20em;
width: 75%;
width: auto;
```

I believe you want:

```
.style('width', (d) => {
  return parseInt(d.age) + 'px';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're applying width or height to svg or svg elements, use `.attr()` instead of `.style()`. In this case, you can use numbers, no `px` needed. If you don't specify any unit, it will be assumed to be `px`. If you're using width and height in `style` attribute, you must specify a unit, no matter what element.

```js
const width = 400,
  height = 200;
  
const svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("background", "steelblue")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 200)
  .attr("fill", "tomato");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@6.3.1/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```